# Git - why does the number of objects differ between my two Git clones?

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I have two local repositories that were cloned from a same remote. I pulled all changes to both local repositories for all branches **but the number of objects shown when calling `git gc` for example (or `git pull`) differs...**

**Does it mean the two repositories are not in-sync?**

The number of 'in-pack' objects is shown by `git count-objects -v`:

```
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: <THIS NUMBER HERE>
packs: 1
size-pack: <a size>
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0
```

or alternatively by `git gc`

```
Counting objects: <HERE>, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (yyyy/yyyy), done.
Writing objects: 100% (<HERE>/<HERE>), done.
Total <HERE> (delta xxxx), reused <HERE> (delta zzzz)
```

**Shouldn't the number of objects be the same for my two local repositories?** (since they are both up-to-date?)

Comment: Objects are a part of Git's internal structure, and not the correct level to check if two repositories are "equal". Instead, you can compare the output of `git branch -av` in each repository. This will show you if any branches are missing from one repository or the other, or if any branches have different heads. It won't include the stashes, though, or any other non-branch things such as tags or the reflog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should check what references you have by running `git for-each-ref` (or similar) in each repository.  Some references, including things like those in the [stash](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html), will hold on to objects that are likely to appear only in one repository.

That aside, an "active" git repository (by "active" I mean one in which you edit and `git add` and `git commit` and occasionally `git rebase`, `git reset`, `git stash`, and so on) accumulates a number—potentially a very large number—of "deleted, but not yet expired" commits.  (It accumulates deleted and expired commits too, but you mentioned `git gc` above, and that actually removes these, so that they no longer contribute to the object count.)

If you expire all reflogs and prune everything (note, this is removing all your safety belts and harnesses, tossing your high-wire balance pole aside, ditching all the lifeboats, and opening the outer airlocks<sup>1</sup> ... i.e., don't do this on a whim):

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --expire-unreachable=now --all
git prune --expire=now
```

and then run `git gc`, you should get the minimum number of objects.  (If both repositories are active you might have to do this on both.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Apparently, you're doing this on a high wire attached to a car being driven on a boat sailing on an ocean inside a space habitat.  Wow. :-)

Comment: Yes both repos are active (`git add/pull/merge/commit/reset...`). Now `git pull` on all branches says "up-to-date" so I'll discard one of the repositories as soon as I'm sure they're in sync with regard to the # of objects :-) Thanks.

Comment: BTW I didn't mention the accumulated unreachable blobs that you get with `git add` followed by a second `git add` before `git commit`.  Those will get cleaned out by the `git prune --expire=now` though.

Comment: I tried both commands (`git reflog expire...` and `git prune...`) but, unfortunately, it didn't change the number of objects shown by `git gc` or `git count-objects -v`...

Comment: @Bludzee: hmm (and, yes, that edit—put in the missing `expire`—was correct, sorry about that).  Could be interesting to see what objects differ between the two repositories.  Also, even before that, maybe a quick `git for-each-ref` just to make sure they have all the same references...

Comment: `git for-each-ref` shows there is a spurious stash in the clone that has more objects: `effe0b84c6cdb2bc6f1fc033fc47713fe31561ca commit refs/stash`. I tried to dispose of it using `git stash drop` but it failed with this error message: `refs/stash@{0} is not valid reference`...

Comment: Finally `git stash clear` correctly discarded the spurious stash. And now the `in-pack` number of objects is the same for both repositories! Thanks.